# File to string conversion in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
dictionary = file . read()
```

I'm currently creating a cipher solver for the 2017 cipher challenge
I have a word document of fifty eight thousand words but i cannot get the file as a string in python 2.7.9
I have tried many thing i have read online such as the above code but to no avail.
I also need this to be easy to understand as i am new to python

Thanks!Don't be negative be constructive!

The word are from:
http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt

Comment: There are many tutorials on line for how to read files in Python.  Where are you stuck with all of those?  Pick one and give us a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: At least comment before you downvote

Comment: In order to comply with the rules of this forum you should edit your question in line with comment #1 above.

Comment: Please don't deface your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should consult some code examples on the web for reading a file. You need something like:

```
fp = open(fname, "r")
lines = fp.readlines()
for line in lines:
   do_something_with_the_lines
fp.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is:

```
with open("dictionary.txt") as f: # Open the file and save it as "f"
    dictionary = f.read()         # Read the content of the file and save it to "dictionary"
```

If you want to read it from a website, try this:

```
import urllib2
dictionary = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt").read() # Open the website from the url and save its contents to "dictionary"
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should check this out for what you're trying to do (http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python)

This should be helpful

Comment: FYI I just happened to look at this page and saw many typos and indentation errors.  In a tutorial aimed at beginners this is not good.